# BeautifulSoup object contents to string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am working to extract table and table header elements from the web page. The table elements have been extracted with no issues. However, I cannot extract the h2 class into individual strings. I can either import all as beautifulsoup objects or as one long string containing all h2 elements. How can I extract the elements to a table or list as individual string objects?

```py
scr = 'https://tv.varsity.com/results/7361971-2022-spirit-unlimited-battle-at-the- 
boardwalk-atlantic-city-grand-ntls/31220'
    
scr1 = requests.get(scr)
```

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(scr1.text, "html.parser")
sp3 = soup.find(class_="full-content").find_all("h2")
```

Here are two methods I have tried so far.

```py
comp = pd.DataFrame(sp3[0], dtype=str)
div1a = div.drop(div.iloc[0].name)
div2a = div1a.drop(div1a.iloc[0].name)
```

also using a for loop

```py
data = []
for a in soup.find(class_="full-content").find_all("h2"):
    a = str(a.text)
    data.append(a)

x = ",".join(map(str, data))
print(x)
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get the text of each h2 element in a list or use a for loop that iterates over the h2 elements.

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://tv.varsity.com/results/7361971-2022-spirit-unlimited-battle-at-the-boardwalk-atlantic-city-grand-ntls/31220'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
sp3 = soup.find(class_="full-content").find_all("h2")
headers = [elt.text for elt in sp3]
print(headers)
```

Output:

```
['2022 Spirit Unlimited: Battle at the Boardwalk Atlantic City Grand Ntls Nationals Results',
'Level 5 & 6 Results', 'L5 Junior', ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That seems to work well for me.